# Using roi functions while zoomed in on a Figure (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm writing a program that lets users do 2D Fourier filtering of an image.  The image is displayed in a Figure and the user can add masks using `imellipse` and `roipoly` functions that are applied to the frequency domain data.

The question: is it possible to use `imellipse` and `roipoly` while zoomed in on the Figure?

I've tried zooming in and using the two function, but it just zooms out and makes filtering DC frequencies really tough.  If `imellipse` and `roipoly` are on and Zoom is selected, I can't get the functions back.  Googling didn't turn up anything.

Version: 2013b

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do the following with `imcrop` routinely, and I just verified it with `imellipse`:

1. Click the Zoom In toolbar button (notice it stays selected and you will have a magnifying glass mouse pointer).
2. Zoom into a region of the image.
3. Click the Zoom In toolbar again (you will get the normal arrow pointer back). **This is the important part.** The image will stay zoomed.
4. Run `imellipse`, etc..

Comment: Thanks!  Works perfectly in 2013b.  Now I can chop out that DC like a boss :)